# Get value ViewPager without recreating the object

Tags: java, android

I use ViewPager() and use the following code:

```
viewPage = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPage);
        viewPage.setAdapter(new ContainerFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext(), 2));
        viewPage.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                Log.d("dfdf", String.valueOf(menu.get()));

            }
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {


            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
        });
```

In the *logs I need to write* down the value of the element location '**menu**' axis *Y*, for this, I use the method '**menu.getY()**'.
The only thing is that he does not begin to scroll the screen, this value will be equal to **0.0**!!! How to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: what is your menu.get(y) here.. ?? What is y?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can explicitly create a listener here and set it on viewpager

```
public class DetailOnPageChangeListener extends ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener {

        private int currentPage;

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            currentPage = position;
        }

        public final int getCurrentPage() {
            return currentPage;
        }
    }
```